# Return null and empty List after unmarsal

Tags: java, xml, unmarshalling, jaxb2

I used this XSD: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sample-xsd-file-customers-and-orders1

And this XML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sample-xml-file-customers-and-orders-linq-to-xml-2

I generated from XSD the Java classes with Jaxb, I created the unmarshall method, but every value return null. Please help!

This is my main Class:

```
        try {

            SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            Schema xsdSchema = sf.newSchema(new File(%Here is the PATH% \\CustomerAndOrders.xsd"));

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            unmarshaller.setSchema(xsdSchema);
            unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new MyValidationEventHandler());
            File file = new File("%Here is the PATH% \\ XMLTestFile.xml");
            System.out.println(file.getName());

            Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
            CustomerType orderT = new CustomerType();
            Customers cust = new Customers();

            for (CustomerType cT : cust.getCustomer()) {
                System.out.println(cT.getContactName());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class MyValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println("\nEVENT");
            System.out.println("SEVERITY:  " + event.getSeverity());
            System.out.println("MESSAGE:  " + event.getMessage());
            System.out.println("LINKED EXCEPTION:  " + event.getLinkedException());
            System.out.println("LOCATOR");
            System.out.println("    LINE NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
            System.out.println("    COLUMN NUMBER:  " + event.getLocator().getColumnNumber());
            System.out.println("    OFFSET:  " + event.getLocator().getOffset());
            System.out.println("    OBJECT:  " + event.getLocator().getObject());
            System.out.println("    NODE:  " + event.getLocator().getNode());
            System.out.println("    URL:  " + event.getLocator().getURL());
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Genarated classes with Jaxb:

```
package XMLBeans;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "customers",
    "orders"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Root")
public class Root {

    @XmlElement(name = "Customers", required = true)
    protected Root.Customers customers;
    @XmlElement(name = "Orders", required = true)
    protected Root.Orders orders;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customers property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Root.Customers }
     *     
     */
    public Root.Customers getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the customers property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Root.Customers }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustomers(Root.Customers value) {
        this.customers = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the orders property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link Root.Orders }
     *     
     */
    public Root.Orders getOrders() {
        return orders;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the orders property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link Root.Orders }
     *     
     */
    public void setOrders(Root.Orders value) {
        this.orders = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="Customer" type="{}CustomerType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "customer"
    })
    public static class Customers {

        @XmlElement(name = "Customer")
        protected List<CustomerType> customer;

        public List<CustomerType> getCustomer() {
            if (customer == null) {
                customer = new ArrayList<CustomerType>();
            }
            return this.customer;
        }

    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="Order" type="{}OrderType" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "order"
    })
    public static class Orders {

        @XmlElement(name = "Order")
        protected List<OrderType> order;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the order property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
         * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
         * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
         * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the order property.
         * 
         * <p>
         * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
         * <pre>
         *    getOrder().add(newItem);
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         * <p>
         * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
         * {@link OrderType }
         * 
         * 
         */
        public List<OrderType> getOrder() {
            if (order == null) {
                order = new ArrayList<OrderType>();
            }
            return this.order;
        }

    }

}
```

CustomerType class

```
package XMLBeans;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchemaType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "CustomerType", propOrder = {
    "companyName",
    "contactName",
    "contactTitle",
    "phone",
    "fax",
    "fullAddress"
})
public class CustomerType {

    @XmlElement(name = "CompanyName", required = true)
    protected String companyName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ContactName", required = true)
    protected String contactName;
    @XmlElement(name = "ContactTitle", required = true)
    protected String contactTitle;
    @XmlElement(name = "Phone", required = true)
    protected String phone;
    @XmlElement(name = "Fax")
    protected String fax;
    @XmlElement(name = "FullAddress", required = true)
    protected AddressType fullAddress;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "CustomerID")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "token")
    protected String customerID;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the companyName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the companyName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCompanyName(String value) {
        this.companyName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the contactName property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getContactName() {
        return contactName;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the contactName property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setContactName(String value) {
        this.contactName = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the contactTitle property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getContactTitle() {
        return contactTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the contactTitle property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setContactTitle(String value) {
        this.contactTitle = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the phone property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the phone property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setPhone(String value) {
        this.phone = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the fax property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getFax() {
        return fax;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the fax property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setFax(String value) {
        this.fax = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the fullAddress property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link AddressType }
     *     
     */
    public AddressType getFullAddress() {
        return fullAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the fullAddress property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link AddressType }
     *     
     */
    public void setFullAddress(AddressType value) {
        this.fullAddress = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the customerID property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCustomerID() {
        return customerID;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the customerID property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCustomerID(String value) {
        this.customerID = value;
    }

}
```

Here is my sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Root>  
  <Customers>  
    <Customer CustomerID="GREAL">  
      <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>  
      <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>  
      <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>  
      <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>  
      <FullAddress>  
        <Address>2732 Baker Blvd.</Address>  
        <City>Eugene</City>  
        <Region>OR</Region>  
        <PostalCode>97403</PostalCode>  
        <Country>USA</Country>  
      </FullAddress>  
    </Customer>  
  </Customers>  
  <Orders>  
    <Order>  
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>  
      <EmployeeID>6</EmployeeID>  
      <OrderDate>1997-05-06T00:00:00</OrderDate>  
      <RequiredDate>1997-05-20T00:00:00</RequiredDate>  
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-05-09T00:00:00">  
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>  
        <Freight>3.35</Freight>  
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>  
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>  
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>  
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>  
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>  
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>  
      </ShipInfo>  
    </Order>   
    <Order>  
      <CustomerID>LETSS</CustomerID>  
      <EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>  
      <OrderDate>1998-02-12T00:00:00</OrderDate>  
      <RequiredDate>1998-03-12T00:00:00</RequiredDate>  
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1998-02-13T00:00:00">  
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>  
        <Freight>90.97</Freight>  
        <ShipName>Let's Stop N Shop</ShipName>  
        <ShipAddress>87 Polk St. Suite 5</ShipAddress>  
        <ShipCity>San Francisco</ShipCity>  
        <ShipRegion>CA</ShipRegion>  
        <ShipPostalCode>94117</ShipPostalCode>  
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>  
      </ShipInfo>  
    </Order>  
  </Orders>  
</Root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JAXB-generated class for customer is named `CustomerType` under the parameter `name` of the annotation `@XmlType`, but on the xml that you provide the single customer tag is named simply `Customer`.

Change any declaration in your java classes from `CustomerType` into `Customer`

**EDIT:** 
By reading the XSD file, I see that it is inconsistent with the effective content of the XML file: so I wonder that something else might be broken?

**EDIT 2:**
As you stated in the comment you can un-marshall the xml file correctly after the above stated change, but cannot retrieve the data in the for-each loop: that is because of a different issue of a very simple nature: you are iterating over `cust` which was assigned to be a completely new instance of `Customers` and un-related from the content effectively un-marshalled inside `root`.
So please refactor the code of the main class by changing:

```
Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
CustomerType orderT = new CustomerType();
Customers cust = new Customers();
for (CustomerType cT : cust.getCustomer()) {
    System.out.println(cT.getContactName());
}
```

to:

```
Root root = (Root) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
for (CustomerType cT : root.getCustomers.getCustomer()) {
    System.out.println(cT.getContactName());
}
```

Comment: HI Katuiros!  The declaration change doesn't work! In debug mode i see the values, but the for each on CustomerType doesnt work, doesnt enter in the List.

Comment: So you were able to un-marshall all of the content of the xml inside instances of Root, Customers and CustomerType, but when you try to access the list of CustomerType in the instance of Customers, you cannot get out the content, is that what you are saying?

And were you able to un-marshal the content of the xml feed after changing the declaration as i suggested?

Comment: First question: Yes
Second question: Yes

Comment: Katuiros! Thank you!